# Pass an object from a event function as a parameter to another event function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

I'm trying to pass a data object that retrieved from a server in func1 to func2 as a parameter, but not working as i wanted, see code:

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#page"),
    events: {
        "click #button1" : "func1",
        "click #button2" : "func2"
    },
    ......................,

    func1: function(){
         var registData = {myData: "123"};
         // post registData to server
         $.post('/', registData, function(data){
         // server response with a data
          this.func2(data);
    },

    func2: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
})
```

Comment: What's not working? What's happening?

Comment: @fencliff I got something that is not it should be and i dont know what it is: `jQuery.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", isDefaultPrevented: function, timeStamp: 1359980971880, jQuery18305322081046178937: true…}`

Answer (score 2):

`this` in your callback isn't the object where `func2` was defined.

You can do this :

```
func1: function(){
     var that = this;
     var registData = {myData: "123"};
     // post registData to server
     $.post('/', registData, function(data){
         // server response with a data
         that.func2(data);
     });
},
```

Comment: ty for reply, i got a object that is not what it should be: `jQuery.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", isDefaultPrevented: function, timeStamp: 1359980971880, jQuery18305322081046178937: true…}...... `

Comment: What's the problem ? Maybe you want its originalEvent property ?